# Node Call Export on Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm banging my head for not learning from the basics and just jumping in.

I'm building an API that returns the SSL Certificate status of a domain.
It's working fine on console.log but the JSON output is empty, obviously because the exports get executed before the https request ends.

How do I incorporate the exports in response.on(end) function?
Thanks a lot!

```js
function getSSL(domain) {

    var options = {
        host: 'www.'+domain+'.com',
        method: 'get',
        path: '/'
    };

    var isAuth = false;

    callback = function(response) {

        response.on('data', function () {
            isAuth = response.socket.authorized;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(isAuth);
        });

    }   
    
  var req = https.request(options, callback).end();
}

exports.findByDomain = function (req, response) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    sslCheck = getSSL(id);
    response.send(sslCheck);
};
```

Comment: `getSSL` needs a callback as the second param to return the data. It'll look like: `getSSL(id, function(data) { response.send(data) });`

Comment: [Related/dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), whereby `isAuth` is the thing you want to be passing to an ultimate callback function, probably defined within your `findByDomain` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `response.send(sslCheck);` gets executed before `getSSL(id);` has a chance to finish. You need to send in a callback so it can be executed **after** `getSSL(id);` finishes:

```
function getSSL(domain, callback) {

    var options = {
        host: 'www.'+domain+'.com',
        method: 'get',
        path: '/'
    };

    var isAuth = false;

    var httpCallback = function(response) {

        response.on('data', function () {
            isAuth = response.socket.authorized;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(isAuth);
            callback(isAuth);
        });

    }

  var req = https.request(options, httpCallback).end();
}

exports.findByDomain = function (req, response) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    getSSL(id, function(sslCheck) {
        response.send(sslCheck);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked fine!
Now I just need to investigate a better way of retrieving SSL information without the overhead of the whole firstpage html.